# Struts 2 jquery editable grid,want to disable inline add button

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a struts2 jquery grid. In which , I am trying to disable the inline add icon.

I tried using the jquery code:

```
$('#attrAssignmentGrid').jqGrid('inlineNav','#attrAssignmentGrid_pager', {
      add : false,
      addicon : "ui-icon-plus" 
});
```

But nothing is getting refelected in my struts 2 jquery grid.
Tried using navigatorInlineEditButtons=false, but it disables every button in the inline navigator. I need only add button to be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically navigatorInlineEditButtons=false works for me. As hiding that, will solve the problem of inline add and save. Which is inbuilt, that is saving empty row.